# VirtualBoxのゲストOSが起動しない

Tags: virtualbox

ノートPC(windows7)にVirtualBox(5.2.6)をいれて、仮想マシンubuntu(14.04)を使ってプログラムしていたのですが、バッテリー切れで電源が落ちてしまい、起動しなおしてからVirtualBox自体は動くのですが、仮想マシンがスタートできない状態です。昨日の夜からこの状態です。

**エラーコード**

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu (64 bit).

The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

**ログメッセージ**

```
VirtualBox VM 5.2.6 r120293 win.amd64 (Jan 15 2018 14:58:38) release log
00:00:01.507798 Log opened 2018-01-27T09:29:04.211858100Z
00:00:01.507800 Build Type: release
00:00:01.507802 OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:01.507804 OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:01.507805 OS Service Pack: 1
00:00:01.569302 DMI Product Name: HP ProBook 430 G1
00:00:01.572829 DMI Product Version: A3009DF10303
00:00:01.572837 Host RAM: 3977MB (3.8GB) total, 1042MB available
00:00:01.572840 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
00:00:01.572841 Process ID: 7588
00:00:01.572842 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:01.573314 SSM: Bad footer magic: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00:00:01.573382 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={VM cannot start because the saved state file 'C:\Users\*******\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu (64 bit)\Snapshots\2018-01-26T08-42-39-313969400Z.sav' is invalid (VERR_SSM_INTEGRITY_FOOTER). Delete the saved state prior to starting the VM}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:01.573894 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up issue detected...
00:00:01.573971 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
```

色々調べましたが、再インストール等を行っても変化がなかったです。Windows Updateは1/16に行ったので、関係ないと思われます。
どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ログ 573382の中に「不正なステートファイル（.sav）を削除しろ」といった内容があるのですが、すでに試されていますか？

Comment: 試しましたが，ログのエラー部分がVERR_SSM_INTEGRITY_FOOTERから，確かVERR_SSM_NOT_FOUNDに変わっただけでした．

Comment: まだ読み進めてないですが、該当コードはたぶんここでしょうか https://github.com/mdaniel/virtualbox-org-svn-vbox-trunk/blob/master/src/VBox/VMM/VMMR3/SSM.cpp#L7626 。Saved State Managerが出してるエラーなのでステートを破棄する方向の対処だと思うのですが……

Comment: また Windows 7と「E_FAIL (0x80004005)」でかなり古いですが解決済みのトピックがフォーラムにあります。こちらはすでに試されていますか？
 https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196 もし今までに試したことがあれば質問に全て追記してくださると助かります

Comment: 返信遅れてしまいすみません．元の仮想マシンをコピーし，新しい仮想マシンを作ることで，動作しました．ありがとうございました．

Answer (score 2):

元の仮想マシンをコピーし，新しい仮想マシンを作ることで，動作しました．

---

この回答は [@gorochan さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41243/virtual-box%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment42236_41243) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。

Comment: 最近同様な現象が発生しました。結局はディスクイメージだけを再利用して、VMを作り直すことで解決しました。